# How to more accurate aggregate values in dataframe by python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

[image]

This is my result made by code

```
il = wb[["region","incomeLevel"]]
count_il = il.groupby("incomeLevel")
count_il.count()
```

It looks fine, but how can I made it perfect that the result gives me more detailed information about each region?

For example, the raw name is income level, and the column name is including below:

[image]

and the result shows each region's value. Eg.,

```
           East Asia & pacific      South Asia

High income       7                      6
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find another way to solve the problem by myself:

```
il.groupby(['region', 'incomeLevel'])['region'].count()
```

and it shows the result below:

```
region                      incomeLevel        
East Asia & Pacific         High income            14
                            Low income              1
                            Lower middle income    13
                            Upper middle income    10
Europe & Central Asia       High income            37
                            Low income              1
                            Lower middle income     6
                            Upper middle income    14
Latin America & Caribbean   High income            18
                            Low income              1
                            Lower middle income     4
                            Upper middle income    19
Middle East & North Africa  High income             8
                            Low income              2
                            Lower middle income     5
                            Upper middle income     6
North America               High income             3
South Asia                  Low income              2
                            Lower middle income     5
                            Upper middle income     1
Sub-Saharan Africa          High income             1
                            Low income             27
                            Lower middle income    14
                            Upper middle income     6
Name: region, dtype: int64
```